# Media queries for gridbox are not working

Tags: css, media-queries

Hi I am trying to make items in my gridbox responsive and I would like to resize some of the items inside the box. Although, when I try to put a media query to resize the boxes, it does not resize them and in the chrome window it shows a line through the query. I would also like to note that the boxes in the grid I am trying to place a media query on were created in javascript and are created after the media query is loaded. Does anyone know why this is happening.

edit:Here is the code

HTML:

```
<head>
<CSS MEDIA FILE>
</head>
<body>
<div class='ContinerForRandomBoxes'></div>

<JS FILE>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media(min-width:600px) and (max-width:800px){
  .RandomBox:nth-child(1), .RandomBox:nth-child(2){
      display: none;
  }
 .RandomBox:nth-child(3){
      grid-row-start: 8;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 13;
    grid-column-end: 9;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
var AddRandomBoxSelect = 0;
function AddRandomBox(Cstart, Cend, RStart, Rend, color,Head,Headleft,Body,Bodyleft, buttonLeft, buttonWidth, fontColor, bodyFontColor, delay, BodyTop){
    var RandomBox = "<div class='RandomBox' data-aos='fade-up' data-aos-delay="+delay+" data-aos-easing='ease-out-back'><h2 class='RBHead'>"+Head+"</h2><br/><p class='RBBody'>"+Body+"</p><button class='RBButton'>Let's Go!</button></div>";
    if(BodyTop == undefined){
        BodyTop = '13%';
    }
    var HeadTop = '12%';
    var buttonTop = '74%';
    var buttonHeight = '12%';
    $('.ContinerForRandomBoxes').append(RandomBox);
    var SelectRandomBox = $('.RandomBox')[AddRandomBoxSelect];
    $(SelectRandomBox).css('grid-column-start',`${Cstart}`);
    $(SelectRandomBox).css('grid-column-end',`${Cend}`);
    $(SelectRandomBox).css('grid-row-start',`${RStart}`);
    $(SelectRandomBox).css('grid-row-end',`${Rend}`);
    $(SelectRandomBox).css('background-color',`${color}`);
    var SelectHead = $('.RBHead')[AddRandomBoxSelect];
    $(SelectHead).css('color',`${fontColor}`);
    $(SelectHead).css('left', `${Headleft}`);
    $(SelectHead).css('top', `${HeadTop}`);
    var SelectBody = $('.RBBody')[AddRandomBoxSelect];
    $(SelectBody).css('color',`${bodyFontColor}`);
    $(SelectBody).css('left',`${Bodyleft}`);
    $(SelectBody).css('top',`${BodyTop}`);
    var SelectButton = $('.RBButton')[AddRandomBoxSelect];
    $(SelectButton).css('top',`${buttonTop}`);
    $(SelectButton).css('left',`${buttonLeft}`);
    $(SelectButton).css('width', `${buttonWidth}`);
    $(SelectButton).css('height', `${buttonHeight}`);
    AddRandomBoxSelect++;
}
AddRandomBox('1','8','1','span 7','rgb(0, 114, 144)','Content','12.2%','Content','12%','12%','25%','white','white', '0');
AddRandomBox('8','span col6-end','1','span 7','#d5f6ea','Content','10.2%',`Content`,'10%','10%','25%','rgb(60,60,60)','black','100');
AddRandomBox('1','9','8','13','peachpuff','Content','10.2%',`Content`,'10%','10%','25%','rgb(60,60,60)','black','0','10%');
AddRandomBox('9','col12-end','8','13','rgb(96, 250, 136)','Content','10.2%',`Content`,'10%','10%','25%','rgb(60,60,60)','black','100','10%');
AddRandomBox('1','col6-end','13','19','rgb(96, 250, 136)','Content','10.2%',`Content`,'10%','10%','25%','rgb(60,60,60)','black','0','10%');
```

Comment: would you share some code it would be helpful

Comment: Sorry it took so long

Comment: Can you please post the rendered HTML? The JS doesn't really help us see the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I have found the answer. It turns I had to render the css after the js page and then it works fine. So sorry for wasting your time